# Can not access flows and processes via UI installed with 2GP / SFDX on target org

Tags: process-builder, salesforcedx

I have some second generation packages (2GP) that contain processes and flows. I am working with the API Version 44.0.
When pushing/pulling the flows on/from scratch orgs, they work easily. But after compiling package versions, the flows are not accessible via the UI anymore, if I install the package versions on any target orgs (Tested with Scratch Orgs, Sandboxes and my Production environment). See screenshot of error message.

Does anybody has a clue? I am quite confident, that this used to work; however I am not sure if this appeared only after I updated from [v43 to v44](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm)

[image: Process UI Error Message]

For anybody who comes here with the same problem, here's at least a workaround how to get rid of the corrupted meta data:

1. Prepare a v43 Metadata deployment that adds a .flowDefinition-File to deactivate the whole flow/process
2. Also add necessary test classes and comment out the particular tests that might fail because of the deactivated flow
3. Deploy the package
4. Visit the Setup > Installed Packages > Select corrupted package > View Components and "remove" the Flow/Process from the components list of the package
5. You can now delete the flow via UI, even though are still unable to access it